# Find pattern in HTML elements with Selenium/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this html that I am trying to scrape from surfing heats

```
     <div class="event-round">
           <div id="heat-85940" class="new-heat  new-heat--status-completed new-heat--athletes-4">
           <div id="heat-85941" class="new-heat  new-heat--status-completed new-heat--athletes-4">
           <div id="heat-85942" class="new-heat  new-heat--status-completed new-heat--athletes-4">
           <div id="heat-85943" class="new-heat  new-heat--status-completed new-heat--athletes-4">
     <div>
```

I have a loop created to scrape the heats on each page, but because the heat ID is changing on each page (ie not always starting at 85940), I can only get 1 page worth without manually changing the range i loop.

For one page, my code looks like this:

```
heat_count = len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'new-heat-hd-name').text)

for h in range(heat_count):
    for i in range(4):
        name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="heat-8594{h}"]/div/div[2]/div[{i + 1}]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
```

I'm looking for a way to search within the html to find `heat-85940` and then start from there instead of manually finding it for each page.

Comment: Can you include a url or more examples of the elements you want to scrape from different pages?

Comment: @Driftr95 added html example

Comment: @bs2012- I meant enough to test some code on, with the nested divs and spans, and so that I could see how  `new-heat-hd-name`  class relates to the `heat-` ids.... anyway, I've posted something that *might* work - I couldn't test it, so please let me know if it works

Comment: Btw, can you really apply `.text` to multiple elements at once like you're doing in the `heat_count` line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Here I am writing only the starting section of the XPath - ie, how to handle the dynamic value 'id="heat-85940"', pls fill in the remaining XPath, because you didn't post the URL and full HTML source.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[starts-with(@id,'heat-')]...<remaining XPath until the element>")
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[starts-with(@id,'heat-8594')]...<remaining XPath until the element>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```py
# heats = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id,"heat-")]')
heats = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*[id^="heat-"]')
for heat in heats:
    names = heat.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span')
    for n in names[:4]:
        name = n.text
```

or

```py
# heats = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id,"heat-")]')
heats = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*[id^="heat-"]')
for heat in heats:
    for i in range(4):
        name = heat.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/div/div[2]/div[{i + 1}]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
```

(I can't test these without more of your html so I'm not quite confident in any of them.)